# Function not lauching upon key press

Tags: python, events, tkinter

So I have this code in Python:

```
class Chronometre(Frame):                                       

    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
        self._start = 0.0        
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0
        self._running = 0
        self.timestr = StringVar()               
        self.makeWidgets()    

    def _update(self):
        self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        self._timer = self.after(50, self._update)

    def Start(self):                                                     
        if not self._running:            
            self._start = time.time() - self._elapsedtime
            self._update()
            self._running = 1        

    def Stop(self):                                    
        if self._running:
            self.after_cancel(self._timer)            
            self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start    
            self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
            self._running = 0

    def Reset(self):                             
        self._start = time.time()         
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0    
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)

def Clavier(event):
    print(event.keysym)
    if event.keysym == 'a' :
        sw = Chronometre()
        sw.Start()
        sv = Chronometre()
        sv.Start()
    if event.keysym == 'z' :
        sw = Chronometre()
        sw.Stop()
    if event.keysym == 'e' :
        sv = Chronometre()
        sv.Stop()
    if event.keysym == 'r' :
        sw = Chronometre()
        sw.Reset()
        sv = Chronometre()
        sv.Reset()

def main():
    root = Tk()

    root.bind("<Key>",Clavier)
```

A friend of mine is trying to launch a function upon hitting a key, but it doesn't launch the function. Does anybody know why this would happen? I know the program goes into the if statement but it won't launch the function.

Could it be because of the fact that it is in a class?

Answer (score 4):

You don't seem to be instantiating your classes, or calling their methods.

```
if event.keysym == 'a' :
    sw = Chronometre()
    sw.Start()
```

and so on.

Comment: I added the parentheses and it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to run the Tkinter mainloop for it to do anything, like catch keys

```
root.mainloop()
```

Second, the Start() function has variables that have not been declared, so you will get an error the first time through, i.e. self._running and self._elapsedtime.  Also the function _setTime() has not been declared.

Comment: all of these things have already been done, I couldn't add more code than that because otherwise it would say the post had more code than text